# Find the doubling constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

My book says Find the doubling constant for the exponential function:
$$1.05^x$$

I'm not sure how to work this out, and I'm very sorry if this question is stupid, or too easy for this community.

Comment: What is a doubling constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that "doubling constant" means "the value of $x$ for which $1.05^x = 2$" (I have not met the precise terminology before), then you need take logs of both sides:

$$\log(1.05^x) = \log2$$
then 
$$x\log1.05 = \log2$$
so that
$$x = \frac{\log 2}{\log 1.05} = 14.207$$

Comment: I vaguely remember having seen that terminology before (in I think some dynamical systems or physical context). It is sort of the opposite of half-life. So I think your interpretation is sound.

Comment: @Old John: It sounds somewhat more reasonable to assume that it is the value of $x$ for which $1.05^x=2\cdot1.05=2.1$, but I haven't met this terminology before either.

Comment: I took it to mean the value of $x$ that makes $1.05^x$ double what it was when $x=0$, but I might be wrong!

Comment: Math expert, i thank you!

Comment: The "doubling constant" appears in the world of finance in the form of "the rule of 70" which states that if you have, say, an investment with an annual percentage rate of r, then the number of years it will take to double your original investment will be about $70/r$. This magic number comes from the fact that $\ln 2$ is approximately 0.69.